# oracle sql count (or other sufficient aggregate) return zero when row not present

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using an Oracle DB.

I have ONE table: Cars.

It has three fields

Race - Car - Finish

The Car is essentially the ID field.  The race is the name of the race.   The Finish is where the car placed: (1st, 2nd, 4th, DNF).

I want to return how many times a certain car finished at each position, including the zero instances.  So the end result would be:

```
Toyota
Finish         Amount
1st            3
2nd            0
3rd            2
DNF            0
```

I've tried NVL to return zero when a car does not have a 2nd place finish:
select Finish, count(nvl(finish))
from cars where Car = 'Toyota';
But this still only returns the 1st and 3rd place finish counts.

I am pretty much a beginner at SQL so I have been reading up all the zero count questions I could find on this site and elsewhere and cannot generalize the advice to my particular situation.

EDIT TO INCLUDE TABLE:
I am including the table for clarification.  The "Race" field is really not important for this task as I am only trying to count "finish" positions.

```
CAR       RACE      FINISH
Toyota    DCA       1st
Toyota    NYC       3rd
Toyota    ATL       3rd
Toyota    PHI       1st
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this can be done with oracle analytic functions, but don't know the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  f.Finish,
  count(c.Finish) as Finish_Amount
from 
  (select '1st' as Finish from dual
   union all
   select '2nd' from dual
   union all
   select '3rd' from dual
   union all
   select 'DNF' from dual
  ) f
  left join Cars c 
    on f.Finish = c.finish
    and c.Car = 'Toyota'
    --and c.Race = 'Atlanta'
group by f.Finish
order by 1
```

Comment: This still only returns the 1st and 3rd finish counts.  Is it failing because, for example, there is NO row in the table that has the three fields: Toyota, Atlanta, 1st.   There are no records with both Toyota and Atlanta because the car did not exist in that race.  I am sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: @user2154067 - sorry, fixed.

Comment: When I run the above query I still only get the count of 1st and 3rd place finishes.  There are no rows in the table of 2nd or DNF finishes for Toyota but I still want to return zero on those positions.

Comment: @user2154067 - My query returns zeros even on empty table Cars. [look here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eafe8/1)

Comment: My apologies! I must have fat fingered something! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for all the cars

```
select a.f,nvl(cnt,0) cnt
(select '1st' as f from dual
union
select '2nd' as f from dual
union
select '3rd' as f from dual
union
select 'DNF' as f from dual) a,
(select Finish,count(finish) as cnt from cars group by finish) b
where a.f=b.finish(+)
```

If you want only specific car just include a where condition giving car name like

```
(select Finish,count(finish) as cnt from cars where car='MARUTI' group by finish)
```